# Center tick labels when the font is adjusted and text width is given in 'pgfplots' in LaTeX

Tags: pgfplots, vertical-alignment, chinese

As using Chinese, so we can convert Chinese labels to vertical just need to adjust the width of the label. This will work well as it will locate the label centered to the major ticks if not change the font size. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,ctex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.arrows,datavisualization,arrows.meta,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,petri,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \hfill
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},xticklabels={第一个,第二个,第三个,第四个,第五个,第六个,第七个,第八个,第九个,第十个,第十一个},xticklabel style={text width=1em},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision =2,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},scaled ticks=false,width=7.4cm,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=12,ylabel={the first}]
      \addplot[
      scatter,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic,
      scatter/classes={
        a={mark=o,draw=black},
        b={mark=square*},
        c={mark=triangle*}
      },
      ] table [meta=label]{
        x   y   label
        1   0.55476356  c
        2   0.363722187 c
        3   0.81286394  c
        4   0.875783813 c
        5   0.315270863 c
        6   0.827911581 c
        7   0.720070049 c
        8   0.347479399 c
        9   0.27043531  c
        10  0.490422201 c
        11  0.69325892  c
        1   0.735883237 a
        2   0.129003395 a
        3   0.461826926 a
        4   0.756650854 a
        5   0.305755095 a
        6   0.263120301 a
        7   0.38954705  a
        8   0.07894936  a
        9   0.984081129 a
        10  0.712322139 a
        11  0.146583606 a
        1   0.186438911 b
        2   0.483752955 b
        3   0.955453588 b
        4   0.931741157 b
        5   0.307806207 b
        6   0.932585214 b
        7   0.390174549 b
        8   0.397465905 b
        9   0.893646115 b
        10  0.177956892 b
        11  0.250648427 b
      };
      \addplot[mark=none, black,dashed,domain=0:12,samples=2] {0.336};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture} 
  
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xtick={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11},xticklabels={第一个,第二个,第三个,第四个,第五个,第六个,第七个,第八个,第九个,第十个,第十一个},xticklabel style={text width=1em,font=\scriptsize},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/precision =2,/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/fixed zerofill},scaled ticks=false,width=7.4cm,height=4cm,xmin=0,xmax=12,ylabel={the second}]
      \addplot[
      scatter,only marks, point meta=explicit symbolic,
      scatter/classes={
        a={mark=o,draw=black},
        b={mark=square*},
        c={mark=triangle*}
      },
      ] table [meta=label]{
        x   y   label
        1   0.55476356  c
        2   0.363722187 c
        3   0.81286394  c
        4   0.875783813 c
        5   0.315270863 c
        6   0.827911581 c
        7   0.720070049 c
        8   0.347479399 c
        9   0.27043531  c
        10  0.490422201 c
        11  0.69325892  c
        1   0.735883237 a
        2   0.129003395 a
        3   0.461826926 a
        4   0.756650854 a
        5   0.305755095 a
        6   0.263120301 a
        7   0.38954705  a
        8   0.07894936  a
        9   0.984081129 a
        10  0.712322139 a
        11  0.146583606 a
        1   0.186438911 b
        2   0.483752955 b
        3   0.955453588 b
        4   0.931741157 b
        5   0.307806207 b
        6   0.932585214 b
        7   0.390174549 b
        8   0.397465905 b
        9   0.893646115 b
        10  0.177956892 b
        11  0.250648427 b
        
      };
      \addplot[mark=none, black,dashed,domain=0:12,samples=2] {0.778};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Please use XeLaTeX to run code above.

Outputs:

[image]

In the second figure, how to center the labels?